# Convert SQL expression to VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to cast convert this SQL statement in VB, but have been unsuccessful. Can anyone help?

```
declare @factor as int
declare @Date as varchar(30)
set @factor = (Cast(Convert(datetime, @Date) as int) - 33975)- 
    (28 * ((Cast(Convert(datetime, @Date) as int) - 33975)/28))
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Are you asking us to convert this sql statement to a similar statement in VB.NET(rounding to int)? Or are you looking for the [`Math.Truncate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70.aspx) method? (_" integral part of a specified double-precision floating-point number"_)

Comment: Looking for a similar statement in vb.net... This is a formula that is written in SQL within a stored procedure, but I don't want to call the procedure via the Visual Studio 2010 aspx.vb page. So, I need to have this same information work within vb, but unsure about how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to parse the string value to a `DateTime`. Then count the nr. of days from 1900-01-01 to that date.

```
Dim str = "2005-11-14"
Dim dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
Dim baseDate = New DateTime(1900, 1, 1)
Dim intValue = (dateValue - baseDate).TotalDays
```

You can than apply the math operations

```
Dim factor = intValue - 33975 - (28 * (intValue - 33975) / 28)
```